# Cant get the exact plot in pyplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two list and trying to plot as an x,y coordinate to give this graph: 
[image]

but everything failed and this is what I'm getting
[image]

I know I've missed something would be glad if anyt=one could provide pointers. How to plot as rectangle areas and change colour for each segment?

Thank you

Code sample:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
Flow_Rate = [1.7, 1.1, 1.0, 0.8]
Volume = [50, 25, 47, 90]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.fill_between(Volume,Flow_Rate)
plt.title('Flow Rate x Volume')
plt.ylabel('Flow Rate, m3/c')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, include your sample data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I edited to show sample

Comment: I don't understand how the data that you provide relates to the desired plot that you are showing. Can you draw (by hand if necessary) the plot that you are expecting given the data in your code?

Comment: @JKL Have you read the documentation for fill_between? It does exactly what it's supposed to do (given your sample dataset). I suspect that you are interpreting the data in a different way and we need more info to be able to help you. From the documentation:

`Fill the area between two horizontal curves.

The curves are defined by the points (x, y1) and (x, y2). This creates one or multiple polygons describing the filled area.`

In your case you are omitting `y2`, which is set to zero by default

Comment: I want to have a fill in a rectangular format not some other shape.The thing is i have a single value across the x axis. For example a rectangle would be defined by ((x, y1),(x+x2, y1)). The y is from 0 to y in both cases